# Python + Google Map JavaScript API: this.D.bind Error adding Marker to Map

Tags: python, google-maps, marker

I need some help from you.
Executing this code from the Python IDLE console, I have an error:

`"TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.D.bind(this)')"`

and the marker is not visible on the map.

I execute the html code in a browser and I don't have error. The map and the marker is perfect.

I found that the error is in the marker.js file: http://maps.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/32/2/intl/es_419/marker.js

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
html= \
"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDfBy5lpFyQzq7pRpKEBeg7jaXH5hnHul8&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
"""   
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.view = QWebView(self)

        self.setupInspector()

        self.splitter = QSplitter(self)
        self.splitter.setOrientation(Qt.Vertical)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setMargin(0)
        layout.addWidget(self.splitter)

        self.splitter.addWidget(self.view)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.webInspector)

    def setupInspector(self):
        page = self.view.page()
        page.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
        self.webInspector = QWebInspector(self)
        self.webInspector.setPage(page)

        shortcut = QShortcut(self)
        shortcut.setKey(Qt.Key_F12)
        shortcut.activated.connect(self.toggleInspector)
        self.webInspector.setVisible(False)

    def toggleInspector(self):
        self.webInspector.setVisible(not self.webInspector.isVisible())

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    window.view.setHtml(html)
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your application is using a web browser control from the PyQt4. You are experiencing the issue in version 3.32 of Google Maps JavaScript API as suggests the path of marker.js file.

The version 3.32 is currently an experimental version of Maps JavaScript API and it was launched on February 13, 2018. Please note that Google team is actively using new features from EcmaScript 6 in their new versions of API and this might break old browsers or web browser controls that doesn't have full support of EcmaScript 6 features.

You can check the list of supported browsers and embed controls here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport

Unfortunately, PyQt4 is not in the list, so Google doesn't guarantee the API be functional in this environment.

As a workaround you can try to add v=3 parameter in

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>`

to load a release version or v=3.30 to load the frozen version, but this might work only 3 or 6 month, because Google launches new versions of API every 3 months as explained in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

You can consider a different web browser embedded control. For example, you can look at Chromium Embedded Framework.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework

I believe it should work pretty well. According to the documentation this framework embeds a Chromium browser (open-source web browser closely related to the Google Chrome browser) which supports HTML5, EcmaScript6 and uses V8 JavaScript engine.